# Tracking internal search results impressions while filtering bot traffic?

Tags: google-analytics, search-engine, web-crawler, analytics, impressions

I have a search results page which can show between 25 & 100 results at a time

Would like to track impressions for each results set (not clicks)

Ideally I'd have a list of each result's ID that would get saved for each pageview (as well as the page or page type the impressions came from). Then I could aggregate this by ID by day

I had originally wanted to use Google Analytics for this, however I don't think I can add data to GA in this way (even Universal Analytics custom dimensions)

**But I could be wrong? Perhaps I could add data to GA in this way?**

GA Events might have been an option, but this would generate a lot of events; some 25-100 for every pageview! The amount of traffic I receive might make this method impractical

*Note: One of my key reasons for wanting to use GA is that it seems to filter out most bot traffic; I've also done some manual profile filtering to catch a few more bots. Rolling my own solution might mean reinventing the bot-filtering wheel, something I'm not keen on*

**Perhaps there is another service that could be used and provide similar bot filtering behaviour?**

Comment: GA doesn't do special bot filtering, it's just that most bots do not execute javascript (Google collects data via a JS tracker).

Comment: And don't forget UA has not just custom dimensions, it has also custom metrics. If you want numbers to add up then you are looking for a metric.

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff just curious – might you have a source regarding your first comment?

Comment: I've seen some bot traffic come through, specifically traffic from microsoft - mozilla compatible agent. More info in this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118854/what-is-google-analytics-traffic-from-mozilla-compatible-agent).

Comment: Hi, agreed; I do mention above that I've added a profile filter to GA to exclude the traffic from the bots I could identify